# Get all onclick attributes from div - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

So, I'm using requests and bs4 for this one.
I have a website page with a div with a specific class that has a bunch of different onclick att.
Each onclick att is a new page containing the info I'm actually trying to get.

So it's something like:

```
class = "class-name" onclick="url1"
class = "class-name" onclick="url2"
```

And so on.

Inside the url1 and url2 (there's about 500 urls) lies the info I want to actually get. But my first problem right now is that I'm not sure how to go through each onclick and access the pages dynamically.

I was initially thinking about using the class and then getting all onclick att inside a list that I can get through later to get the info through a loop or something, but new ideas are very welcomed.

So, any ideas you guys can share?

Didn't try anything yet, don't know where to start

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and make sure your question has a [mre].

Comment: Before resorting to BS I would try to solve this problem using regex on the plain text.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) with the starting URL, then loop on that queue while it is not empty and find all tags with the `onclick` attribute.

You can use the `select` method to find all divs with an `onclick` attribute:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.select('div[onclick]')
```

You can then loop on `results` and add the new URLs to your queue!

Make sure 2 pages are not referencing themselves because you might end up in an infinite loop. You could use a `set` to store visited URLs, and do not add it to the queue if it is already present in your `set`.